# Add google plus in android using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

As per subject, I want to add google plus (API) in android project using cordova. For this I am using below link tutorial [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus). Actually I can't figure out the problem because I am doing all stapes as per tutorial for iOS and android both. And its work for iOS but not in android. I have both CLIENT ID's. **This is my code.**

```
function login() {
    window.plugins.googleplus.login(
        {
                //'androidApiKey': 'demo2-f2piclv62253f0k177i3se3k30fcbqtq.apps.googleusercontent.com'
                'iOSApiKey': 'demo3462-f2piclv62253f0k177i3se3k30fcbqtq.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        },
        function (obj) {
            document.querySelector("#image").src = obj.imageUrl;
            document.querySelector("#image").style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.querySelector("#feedback").innerHTML = "Hi, " + obj.displayName + ", " + obj.email;
        },
        function (msg) {
            document.querySelector("#feedback").innerHTML = "error: " + msg;
        }
    );
}
```

[image]

Comment: So how doesn't it work: what exactly happens? Any error generated?

Comment: No error, Error on attach image file, Error:No Valid Token.

Comment: And you of course have taken the comment (`//`) off from the front of Android key (_androidApiKey_) for your Android version?

Comment: yes off course. That key are proper..

Comment: To quote the tutorial you were following: "_there is no API key for Android; you app is wired to the Google+ API by listing your package name in the google dev console and signing your apk (which you have done in chapter 4)_". So I assume you have followed the process described [here](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android), right? Because the error message seems related to that.

Comment: It means that I don't have to pass the any key for this and It works ? right. My app bind with my mail id. Or I have to add any file into that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68281/discussion-between-user1500699-and-sanfor).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution, I am using [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) plugin, it works properly for iOS, because passing of iOS clientId through HTML. But for Android you have to pass ClientId in deferent way.
For me :   Project -> Plugins -> android.json

```
        "nl.x-services.plugins.googleplus": {
        "CLIENT_ID": "your_client_ID",
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.demo.googlelogin"
    }
```